# Egypt - Duty free notation on passport

Tags: passports, duty-free, egypt

I went to a duty free in Egypt (outside the airport), they asked me the passport and then when I bought something they wrote on the visa page a note (image attached)
Is this normal? Can this cause problems when exiting?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it would cause a problem, they would have stopped it.

It's very common for airport officials to write something with a ballpen, usually next to their stamp or visa. Although that duty-free employees are not "officials", they are most likely following the instructions of Egyptian officials to ensure that you do not exceed some sort of a duty-free merchandise limit.

Comment: Or maybe signal to someone they should check for the goods actually being exported? Not quite sure how that would work though…

Comment: It may be to prevent you visiting the duty-free shop twice on one day

Comment: Many years ago I repaid the hospitality of an Egyptian guy by accompanying him to a duty free store and buying up my maximum duty free allowance for him.  He was happy to pay as it allowed him to get alcohol for a lot cheaper than he could normally get it.  Marks in my passport would have limited that scheme.

Comment: Can't fathom, @Henry, why store or airport employees would want to prevent a passenger from returning to the store to make additional purchases. Even in countries that don't full support free enterprise (not saying Egypt is in this category), they recognize that a consumer buying more stuff is _good_.

Comment: Getting caught selling tax-free over the legal limit and getting your shop closed down is *bad*